# TCPのスロースタートフェーズでは、cwndは1RTTごとに指数関数的に増加するのに、なぜ「スロー」なのでしょうか？

Tags: tcp

## 背景

[TCP技術入門](https://gihyo.jp/book/2019/978-4-297-10623-2)を読んで、TCPについて勉強しています。

## スロースタート

スロースタートフェーズでは、輻輳ウィンドウサイズ（cwnd）はACKを受け取るごとに、以下のように増加していきます。

```
cwnd = cwnd + mss
```

1RTTごとで見ると、指数関数的に増加します。
https://gihyo.jp/admin/serial/01/tcp-cc/0001 参照

## 質問

スロースタートフェーズでの通信は、何が「スロー」なのでしょうか？
TCPの輻輳制御アルゴリズムの3つのモードの内、「スロースタート」が一番高速です。

- スロースタート
- 輻輳回避
- 高速リカバリ

一番最初のcwndが、たとえば10mssではなく1mssなのが、「スロー」なのでしょうか？
私の感覚だと、「指数関数的に増加する」のはスローではないので、「スロー」という単語を使った理由が気になりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> スロースタートフェーズでの通信は、何が「スロー」なのでしょうか？

指数関数的な増加では初期段階では増加率が小さい(値がなかなか増えない)からです。

> TCPの輻輳制御アルゴリズムの3つのモードの内、「スロースタート」が一番高速です。

そんなことはどこにも書かれていないと思います。

「スロースタート」の目的も平易に書かれているとおもいますので、もう一度きちんと記事を読み直してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: >そんなことはどこにも書かれていないと思います。
どこにも書いていないですね。失礼しました。